# Get data from mysql with json and plot with D3

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I am trying to plot mysql data with d3. I am using php to convert to json format. For testing purposes I followed the steps [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html) and used my own php file on XAMPP. But when I open the the html file in my browser, it always displays a white page.

```
<?php
$mysqli  = mysqli_connect("$host, $username, $password, $dbname");
$mysqli ->set_charset('utf8mb4');
$myArray = array();
 
if($result = $mysqli ->query("SELECT  `date`, `volume` FROM  `sensordata`"))
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
    $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
$result->close();
$mysqli ->close();
?>
```

It echoes in json format like so:

> [{"date": "02-04-2021","volume": "606.51"},{"date": "03-04-2021","volume": "700.51"}]

I use the following code from the Site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang = "en">
    <style> /* set the CSS */

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>

<body>
<script src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    
<script>
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y");

// set the ranges
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
  var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.volume); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("get_data.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.volume = +d.volume;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.volume; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y")));
  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
  </script>
</body>
```

If I use variables like these:

```
var data = [
    {date:"30-05-12",volume:"123"},
    {date:"27-05-12",volume:"67.00"},
    {date:"26-06-12",volume:"89.70"},
    {date:"25-07-12",volume:"99.00"}
];
```

instead of this part:

```
// Get the data
d3.json("get_data.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.volume = +d.volume;
  });
```

everything is fine and the data gets plotted.

All files are in the same folder.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Did you try to view page source (Ctrl+U) ? Also, I suggest to add html closing tag </html> and move scripts out of <body>

Comment: Have you checked the error logs of your server?

Comment: The page source seems fine.

@LajosArpad I checked the error logs but there is nothing suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a JSON file here, not your PHP file:

```
d3.json("get_data.json", ...)
```

So you might want to either request your PHP file, or write the JSON data to a *.json file in advance:

```
if($result = $mysqli ->query("SELECT  `date`, `volume` FROM  `sensordata`"))
{
    ...
    file_put_contents('get_data.json', json_encode($myArray));
}
```

Also, your date format differs between the PHP output you've given and the hardcoded one ('02-04-2021' vs. '30-05-12'). If you like to stick with the latter, you might want to adapt your code's date format string (given it's used by d3.js to also parse a date):

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%y")
```

For d3.json(), see also their [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json).

Comment: The get_data.json was from a previous attempt I forgot to change it back, but with get_data.php it also shows a white page. 
If I request the PHP file, then the date format should be fine with:
`d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y")`
because it is given with century.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it in D3 5.0 they changed the syntax of `d3.json`, with the new syntax my code looks like this:

```
d3.json("get_data.php").then(function(data) {
  
  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.volume = +d.volume;
  });
```

Old code:

```
d3.json("get_data.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.volume = +d.volume;
  });
```

Now the data gets plotted.